# Typing game where code will not let user continue if they do not type the letter correctly

Tags: split, keyboard

I have a typing game that generates a number of words. It asks you how many words you want. If you say 1, it generates 1 word. I want it so the user has to type each letter correctly. If they type the wrong letter, the code won't let them continue until they write the correct one. My code right now. Feel free to change anything.

```
`import random
import time
import keyboard  # using module keyboardf
import string # use this to get the alphabet
from random_word import RandomWords
r = RandomWords`your text`()
start_time=time.time()
def time_convert(sec):
  mins = sec // 60
  sec = sec % 60
  hours = mins // 60
  mins = mins % 60
x=0
print("How many words do you want to do?")
while True:

    sNumOfTimes=input()
    iNumOfTimes=int(sNumOfTimes)
    w = ""
    #message = w
    #message.replace(" ", "")
    for z in range(iNumOfTimes):
        w = r.get_random_word() + " "+ w
        w= w.strip()

    print(w[-100:100])

    while True:
            w = keyboard.read_key()
            al = chr(w)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize operators and compare the inputted/typed char to the current letter in the string. You can do this by using `!=` or `is not` if you are using Python.

With the way you have this currently set up, you want to continue to check for the input of the char `while` the read_key() does not match the same char as the letter in the word.

It seems you may be new to programming and scripting. I would suggest looking up *bracket notation* and *substring referencing* in Python. You will need these to refer to the part of the word you're comparing the input to.

Hope this was helpful.